# set $(element).style.backgroundColor, then check but not working

Tags: javascript

A little bit puzzled by the below code.

```js
function DoColor() {
  document.getElementById("ID").style.backgroundColor = "#F4FFFF";

  alert("ID color = " + $("#ID").css("background-color"));
  // this shows RGB(244, 255, 255) 
  alert($("#ID").css("background-color") === "RGB(244, 255, 255)");
  // this show false   ?????

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ID" onclick="DoColor()">
```

Why is it not alerting `true` as expected?

Comment: I'm still a bit new, so all comments appreciated

Comment: "Any Ideas?" is not a question. What are you asking?

Comment: Try making the comparison not case sensitive.

Comment: Jamiec, its a *why*. we are not learning grammar here :)

Comment: @naveen - I think you missed my point. Just asking "Any ideas?" is not a question [that can be answered]. I am asking the questioner to be specific., not attacking their grammar (which I dont care about).

Comment: @Jamiec, valid point. i was trying to say that OP is a noob here.

Comment: @user3392854 I have tested your code on FF, IE & Chrome and in none of them does the first alert come out uppercase.

Answer (score 7):

You can first convert to lowercase using js [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and then compare:

```js
function DoColor() {
  document.getElementById("ID").style.backgroundColor = "#F4FFFF";

  alert("ID color = " + $("#ID").css("background-color"));
  // this shows RGB(244, 255, 255) 
  alert($("#ID").css("background-color").toLowerCase() === "rgb(244, 255, 255)");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ID" onclick="DoColor()">
```

Comment: Uh, the first string is already lowercase. OP's comment is a lie.

Comment: @Mathletics true but is better to convert to same format as the value you campare to work in any case :)

Comment: Sure, but again, you are converting an already lowercase string to lowercase. If you want to keep what OP intended, you should convert the output to UPPERCASE so that they don't have to change the comparison string.

Comment: Not sure in what browser OP test it but claims is UPERCASE.